# Spark Streaming analytics on a twiter dataset streamed on tcp port

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, data-analysis, apache-spark-mllib

I am streaming a dataset stored locally on a PC in batch sizes of 10 and this is done to TCP port 6100

on the other hand I am fetching these files from this port as JSON files with the format shown below

```
    The outer indices are the indices of each row in a batch and go from 0 - batch_size-1
    The inner indices are the indices of each column in a row and go from 0 - feature_size-1

    {
        '0':{
            'feature0': <value>,
            'feature1': <value>,
            ...
            'featureN': <value>,
        }
        '1':{
            'feature0': <value>,
            'feature1': <value>,
            ...
            'featureN': <value>,
        }
        ...
        'batch_size-1':{
            'feature0': <value>,
            'feature1': <value>,
            ...
            'featureN': <value>,
        }
    }
    '''
```

`I cannot store all batches in memory. At every instant of time, the model must be re-fit on the input batch such that it learns incrementally, one batch at a time.`

considering that I only have **feature0 as the sentiment of tweet and feature1 as tweet text as the data**, how can I perform **classification and preprocessing** provided that I cannot store the entire dataset in the local storage of the application receiving the data, is there any approach I can follow for this kind of machine learning project(pyspark can be used with scikit learn **MLLIB**).

also, can I perform the data analytics on JSON incrementally or only RDD is the way to do so?